# issue with find combinations

Tags: django, database, data-manipulation

I have a list in a mysql data table
This table has 3 fields.
number (INT), price (FLOAT) and name
On the other hand I have another table that gives me three sets of values
Set 1: (x)number - (y)price
Set 2: (x1)number - (y1)price
Set 3: (x2)number - (y2)price

There are several things I know for sure:
**All three sets exist within the combinations of the data table**.
**no row can be used in more than one set**
**There are no unused rows in the table.**

That said, I try to find the combinations within the table that result in set 1, set 2, and set 3
All 3 must occur.
I have tried different approaches, approximations to avoid searching in 25 billion combinations.
Pruning system....
But I'm out of ideas...

The data table changes values and the sets do too. And there may be more than one set, or two, or three...
We are working with less than 100 rows per table.
But whatever I do it always takes a lot of time, and the script does not throw results because of this...

The idea is that sets must be composite. That is, the number and price must match.
not valid, for example (x1) and (y)
You have to combine in both columns (x1) with (y1)... etc...
Any ideas, that it doesn't consume all the resources and that it doesn't take 12 years to complete the task?

number  price   name
435 822,74  demo1
117 194,96  demo 2
30  889,46  demo 3
238 61,62   demo 4
202 59,33   demo 5
487 406,3   demo 6
51  568,33  demo 7
425 135,45  demo 8
410 731,63  demo 9
254 391,58  demo 10
492 295,19  demo 11
122 832,95  demo 12
90  584,97  demo 13
139 338,27  demo 14
491 152,81  demo 15
233 94  demo 16
87  589,67  demo 17
480 92,95   demo 18
200 257,29  demo 19

sets:
9000001 2309    3479,71
9000002 425 135,45
9000003 2249    3884,34

I try with serveral models but nothing seems to work.
With this data range it's easy, and works, but, if you add 10 rows more... then... just... dead...